# How to create PSS and SS activation functions in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, activation-function

I'm using keras with tensorflow backend. My goal is to add my custom activation functions (PSS, SS) but I don't know how can i implement them.

[Positive Smooth Staircase (PSS) activation function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOUNo.png)

Where n is number of output labels, w is a constant.

[Smooth Staircase (SS) activation function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RU1J.png)

Where n is number of output labels (output neurons), c is a constant.

Comment: If you don't know then you should first learn. Learn how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom activation function in Keras, you can define a Python function that takes a `NumPy array as input and returns a NumPy array as output.`

Your function should also support **automatic differentiation**, which means that Keras should be able to automatically compute the derivative of your function in order to backpropagate gradients during training.

Once you have defined your custom activation function, you can add it to Keras as a custom layer. To do this, you can create a subclass of the `keras.layers.Layer` class. In your subclass, you should implement the build() and call() methods.

The `build()` method is responsible for initializing any weights or biases that your layer may need. The `call()` method is responsible for performing the forward pass of your layer.

In the call() method, you should apply your custom activation function to the input data.

You can refer this code and insert your formula in there :

```
import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=my_custom_activation_function, input_shape=(10,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

# Evaluate the model on the test set
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

# Print the accuracy
print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
```